# How to make method defined in a rails engine's application controller automatically available for any other engines which mount it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

Rails 3.2 `engine A` is a logger engine and there is a `logger` method (create an entry in log table) defined in its `application controller`. `Engine B` mounts `engine A` and `engine B's` `model` or `controller` will call logger method in engine A for logging. Is there a way `logger` method in `engine A` could be called by `engine B` without using `include` or `require`? Basically we want `logger` method in `engine A` to be automatically available for any other engines which mount it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your engine's application controllers, inherit from parent application controller:

```
module EngineA
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
  ..
```

Comment: Interesting. We have had this in all of our engine: class ApplicationController < ApplicationController.

Comment: this didnt work for me, `uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)`